# Removing an element from array is not working using Array Function

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a data structure something like

```
{
“_id”: [
“1234”,
“5678”
],
“id”: “docId”
}
```

In this document, I want to write a query to remove “1234” from Array.
I tried this query.

> update sample as d use keys “docId” set d._id=(select
> ARRAY_REMOVE(t._id, “1234”) as _id FROM sample t use keys “docId”);

But instead of updating the existing _id array, it is inserting an additional array. Something like this

```
{
“_id”: [
{
“_id”: [
“5678”
]
}
],
“id”: “docId”
}.
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below N1QL should do it

```
UPDATE sample USE KEYS ["docId"] set `_id` = ARRAY_REMOVE(`_id`,"1234”);
```